# Get objects in query based on user

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a profile page, where I list all the connected benefits to the user, and all benefits that is not connected to the user.

My problem is, that it is not filtering on user, so everyone that logs in, will look like they have a benefit they don't have.

My model:

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_published=True)

class Benefit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    benefits = models.ManyToManyField(Benefit, blank=True, null=True, related_name="used_benefit")
```

My view:

```
class ProfileFrontpage(TemplateView):
    template_name = "profile/dashboard.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ProfileFrontpage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)


            context['used_benefit_list'] = Benefit.published.filter(used_benefit__isnull=False)

            context['unused_benefits_list'] = Benefit.published.filter(used_benefit__isnull=True)


            return context
```

How can I filter Benefits connected to the profile/user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the corresponding filter criteria (This example shows filter on loggedin user )

```
user = self.request.user

benefits = Benefit.published.all()
used_benefit_list = benefits.filter(used_benefit__isnull=False, used_benefit__user = user)
unused_benefits_list = benefits.exclude(id__in = used_benefit_list)

context = {'used_benefit_list': used_benefit_list, 'unused_benefits_list': unused_benefits_list}
```